# JavaScript - What is a boolean for and how/where can I use it?

Tags: javascript, types, boolean

I know i can say that something is true or false but what can I do with it after i did that? There has to be more.

Would be great if someone has got an example.

Comment: You must not have even learned `if`s yet. Look them up. They're a fundamental construct in programming.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i actually did

Comment: Booleans are required to use `if`s though. Are you asking about the importance of `if`s?

Comment: @Carcigenicate so if (something = true){// do this} and that's it?

Comment: It's impossible to overstate how important that is. Your  code will constantly be deciding what action to take based on some condition. `if`s are the most used tool to do the deciding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is basically just making decisions about data, and acting on those decisions. That's a gross oversimplification, but it's generally true.

Booleans (and things that can "act" as Booleans) are important because they're what `if` statements and other conditionals use to decide what to do.

As a very simplified, kind-of real world example, imagine:

```
var correctPassword = "myPassword";
var enteredPassword = (get the entered password);

if (correctPassword == enteredPassword) {
    logUserIn();
} else {
    showBadPasswordError();
}
```

`==` compares two things (strings in this case), and returns a boolean value indicating whether or not the two strings are the same. In this case, if it returns `true`, that means the user's password was correct, so it uses that information to decide whether or not to log the user in.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time.. :)

Comment: @LorisVonlanthen No problem. Note though, that I only took an interest because no code realistically can do anything useful without conditionals. I answered to make sure you understood their importance, but please, for future questions, try to research your topic more. Googling "Javascript boolean" would probably have brought up many tutorials that outlined why they're used.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean,
in other words:
Yes/No 0/1 True/False

I am not good with coding since I am also in the beginner zone. But what I understood from most people is that the boolean is defining the current state of something/code.

is the light on? Yes..then in the code it will be "true"
No?...then "false"

You can use this in If statements...like

```
if (lightOn == true) {
  //then do this
}

else if (lightOff == false) {
 //then do this
}
```

Somehow in that matter.

Comment: That is not valid javascript syntax.

Comment: Oops, my apologies

Comment: Also note, you should never really compare against `true` or `false`, except in very specific circumstances. It's redundant. In your example, just say `if (lightOn) {... ` and `... if (!lightOff) {... `

Comment: many ways to explain it, just had what i typed in mind at that time xD